# How Hive sums across string column?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am using `apache-hive-1.2.1` and created a table :

`test_table : key -> integer and name -> string`

```
key     name
--------------
1       name1
2       name2
3       3
```

I am surprised how following queries are giving the corresponding outputs, since
the column is of type string :

```
select sum(name) from test_table;
Output : 3.0
```

and

```
select avg(name) from test_table;
Output : 3.0
```

Does hive perform aggregations even if the column type is string? How hive does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please refer the code of hive builtin [UDAF-sum()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop.hive/hive-exec/0.7.1-cdh3u1/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDAFSum.java#GenericUDAFSum.GenericUDAFSumDouble) , which takes the signature below *accepts "Only numeric or string type arguments(line-71)*

```
name = "sum", value = "_FUNC_(x) - Returns the sum of a set of numbers"
```

Inside the  GenericUDAFEvaluator() you can find **case STRING: return new GenericUDAFSumDouble();** at line 66 and 67 , which means depending on the primitive type/data type of argument passed, respective aggregation is being done. i.e, for name1,name2(strings) corresponding values for aggregations are from **new DoubleWritable(0);**
So => 0.0+0.0+3 = 3.0

Answer (score 0):

An aggregate function that returns the sum of a set of numbers. Its single argument can be numeric column, or the numeric result of a function or expression applied to the column value. Rows with a NULL value for the specified column are ignored. If the table is empty, or all the values supplied to MIN are NULL, SUM returns NULL.

When the query contains a GROUP BY clause, returns one value for each combination of grouping values.

Return type: BIGINT for integer arguments, DOUBLE for floating-point arguments